# Can'n setup WHL: not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pip

Here is my problem:

Windows 10, Python36. I take pandas on PyPi 0.19 AMD64 (and yes, I tried another one) and install using pip-Win 1.7

```
pip install pandas-0.19.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

And it happens:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas==0.19.2) (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas==0.19.2)

Some packages are also not installed.What should I do?

Comment: I use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads#windows)

Answer (score 0):

Install it from this unofficial binaries repository:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas

But first install all the dependencies shown there, like dateutil (as you've seen is needed).

The packages from this repository are much more likely to work since 64-bit scientific libraries are difficult to compile on Windows.

Comment: @ArielJf. Did you really install the dependency packages? Enter the link above and download and install the dependencies shown ther

Comment: I get error on dateutil pack [link](https://i.paste.pics/713d4b0c0572eadff5a9d64f62cad1cb.png)